# ModuleNotFoundError although package has been installed correctly

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'macrobond_api_constants'`although the package seems to be installed correctly. I checked using `conda list` command.

[image]

https://pypi.org/project/macrobond-api-constants/

The instruction says this should be imported using `import macrobond_api_constants`

I tried to import using both `Spyder` and `PyCharm`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you use python3? if 'yes' then use pip3 not pip to install macrobond_api_constants

Comment: says 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: In PyCharm, in project interpreter window, do you see the macrobond_api_constants package?

Comment: Yes. I can this package.

Comment: so install pip3 first
sudo apt install python3-pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone that wanted to help me with this issue. I contacted lib authors (Macrobond) saying I cannot access library and turns out there was something that they messed. An update has been just released couple days ago. Library is now accessible and works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm import libraries exist in different way. You can try this

**1.** Open **PyCharm**.

**2.** go to `File -> settings -> Project:test(test means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

**3.** after clicking add button and **search the library which you want to install** then **install** it.

finally run the program.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the library I need is not there? And PyCharm shows it has already been installed.

Comment: change your pycharm environment to conda.

Comment: Still nothing. It doesn't find the module in Spyder either.

Comment: If it is not downgrade your python version from 3x to 2x then run the program

Comment: Post that as a answer in here and mark it as accepted. It will help other users who will come with same as your issue